# Scheduling a notification with Alarm Manager Refused to Work -Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, notifications, xamarin.android, alarmmanager

How can i Schedule a `Notification` in Xamarin.Forms so that the Alarm should ring when even the Application is not launched , i tried to implement this in **Project.Droid** but it's not working at all why :

**AlarmReceiver.cs**

```
namespace Diabetes.Droid
{
    [BroadcastReceiver]
    [IntentFilter(new string[] { "android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" }, Priority = (int)IntentFilterPriority.LowPriority)]
    public class AlarmReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
    {

        public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
        {
            if (intent.Action.Equals("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"))
            {



            //Show toast here
            //Toast.MakeText(context, "Hello it's me ", ToastLength.Short).Show();
            var extras = intent.Extras;

            if (extras != null && !extras.IsEmpty)
            {
                NotificationManager manager_ = context.GetSystemService(Context.NotificationService) as NotificationManager;
                var notificationId = extras.GetInt("NotificationIdKey", -1);
                if (notificationId != -1)
                {
                    manager_.Cancel(notificationId);
                }
            }

            //Create intent for action 1 (TAKE)
            var actionIntent1 = new Intent();
            actionIntent1.SetAction("ARCHIVE");
            var pIntent1 = PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(context, 0, actionIntent1, PendingIntentFlags.CancelCurrent);

            //Create intent for action 2 (REPLY)
            var actionIntent2 = new Intent();
            actionIntent2.SetAction("REPLY");
            var pIntent2 = PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(context, 0, actionIntent2, PendingIntentFlags.CancelCurrent);

            Intent resultIntent = context.PackageManager.GetLaunchIntentForPackage(context.PackageName);

            var contentIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(context, 0, resultIntent, PendingIntentFlags.CancelCurrent);

            var pending = PendingIntent.GetActivity(context, 0,
                resultIntent,
                PendingIntentFlags.CancelCurrent);
            //seting an alarm
            MedicationDatabase db = new MedicationDatabase();
            var alarm_list = db.GetAlarmList();
            //Debug.WriteLine(" Time -- : "+ m.ToString());
            var title_ = "Diabetics App";
            var message_ = "\"Hello  we remind you of taking your inslin dosage now";
            foreach (var list in alarm_list)
            {
                var hour = Int32.Parse(list.Substring(0, 2));
                var minute = Int32.Parse(list.Substring(3, 2));
                Intent myintent = new Intent(Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Context, typeof(AlarmReceiver));
                myintent.PutExtra("message", message_);
                myintent.PutExtra("title", title_);
                PendingIntent pendingintent = PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Context, 0, myintent, PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent);

                Java.Util.Date date = new Java.Util.Date();
                Java.Util.Calendar cal = Java.Util.Calendar.Instance;
                cal.TimeInMillis = Java.Lang.JavaSystem.CurrentTimeMillis();
                cal.Set(Java.Util.CalendarField.HourOfDay, hour);
                cal.Set(Java.Util.CalendarField.Minute, minute);
                cal.Set(Java.Util.CalendarField.Second, 0);
                AlarmManager alarmManager = Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Context.GetSystemService(Android.Content.Context.AlarmService) as AlarmManager;
                alarmManager.Set(AlarmType.RtcWakeup, cal.TimeInMillis, pendingintent);
            }

            // Instantiate the Big Text style:
            Notification.BigTextStyle textStyle = new Notification.BigTextStyle();


            var builder =
                new Notification.Builder(context)
                                .AddAction(Resource.Drawable.tick_notify, "ARCHIVE", pIntent1)
                                .AddAction(Resource.Drawable.cancel_notify, "REPLY", pIntent2)
                                .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.ic_launcher)
                                .SetContentTitle("Diabetics Reminder")
                                .SetDefaults(NotificationDefaults.Sound)
                                .SetStyle(new Notification
                                .BigTextStyle()
                                .SetSummaryText("")
                                .SetBigContentTitle(title)
                                .BigText(message)
             ).SetDefaults(NotificationDefaults.All);

            builder.SetContentIntent(pending);

            var notification = builder.Build();


            var manager = NotificationManager.FromContext(context);
            manager.Notify(10010, notification);
        }
        }
    }

    [BroadcastReceiver]
    [IntentFilter(new string[] { "ARCHIVE", "REPLY" })]
    public class CustomActionReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
    {
        public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
        {

            switch (intent.Action)
            {
                case "ARCHIVE":
                    try
                    {
                        MedicationDatabase db = new MedicationDatabase();
                        db.addtracktaken("true");
                        Toast.MakeText(context, "DOSAGE TAKEN", ToastLength.Short).Show();
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
                    }
                    break;
                case "REPLY":
                    try
                    {
                        Toast.MakeText(context, "ARCHIVE", ToastLength.Short).Show();
                        MedicationDatabase db = new MedicationDatabase();
                        db.addtrackmissed("true");
                        Toast.MakeText(context, "DOSAGE MISSED", ToastLength.Short).Show();
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
                    }
                    break;
            }

            var extras = intent.Extras;

            if (extras != null && !extras.IsEmpty)
            {
                NotificationManager manager = context.GetSystemService(Context.NotificationService) as NotificationManager;
                var notificationId = extras.GetInt("NotificationIdKey", -1);
                if (notificationId != -1)
                {
                    manager.Cancel(notificationId);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" package="com.diabetics.Diabetes">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REBOOT" />
    <application android:label="Diabetes">
        <receiver android:name="com.diabetics.Diabetes.AlarmReceiver" android:enabled="true" android:exported="true" android:process=":remote" android:label="AlarmReceiver" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

[Link to the project](https://github.com/huxaiphaer/DiabeticsApp/blob/master/Droid/AlarmReceiver.cs)

Comment: You set `AlarmService` inside of `AlarmReceiver`?  Why you do so, did you have any other code inside your activity where you set `AlarmService`?

Comment: @GraceFeng-MSFT, now how can i make it not to be like that because am still an amatuer in android development please help me editting it, and secondly will the Alarm be able to work even without launching the Application? if at all we implemen your idea?